# .getJSON produce a Download of a File ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I code a .getJSon, It does the job but I get IE to asked to download the file. Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#id').click(function() {
        var dateReport = "01/01/2009";

        $.getJSON('/Report/SendReport', { date: dateReport},
                function(response) {
                    if (response.result == "OK") {
                        $('#OKSendReport').toggle();
                        $('#OKSendReport').html("OK");
                    }
                });
    });
});
```

The code in the controller is

```
 public ActionResult SendReport(string date) {
        //DO Stuff

        return new JsonResult {
            Data = new { result = "OK" }
        };
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you return from your controller? a json-result? a view, where you have manually parsed out some json? a redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `event.preventDefault();` on the click event:

```
$(function() {
    $('#id').click(function(event) {
        var dateReport = "01/01/2009";

        event.preventDefault(); // added this

        $.getJSON('/Report/SendReport', { date: dateReport},
                function(response) {
                    if (response.result == "OK") {
                        $('#OKSendReport').toggle();
                        $('#OKSendReport').html("OK");
                    }
                });
    });
});
```

Comment: I get the following error now: Object does not support this method

Comment: You have to add the `event` arugment in the function callback.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm Are you sure that the Javascript is being triggered in that instance? What is HTML type is #ID? If the JavaScript is not getting called and your controller is trying to route to the json result, I think that could be your problem.